# Laravel second js file

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, panel

I am trying to put JS admin panel code in a separate file and connect it only in admin panel.

1) create `\resources\js\back.js` and insert js

```
require('codemirror');
require('codemirror/lib/codemirror.css');

require('summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.css');
require('summernote/dist/summernote-bs4');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: 150,
    });
});
```

2) add to `webpack.mix.js`

```
.js('resources/js/back.js', 'public/js')
```

3) Add to blade after `app.js`

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/back.js') }}" defer></script>
```

But I have next error -

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I would check your browser debugger to make sure that back.js is included in your project. If not, it may be helpful to do a full browser refresh (Shift + F5 in Chrome) and check again.